# Passing javascript variables(array) to php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a function where the user inputs are stored in a variable in javascript.

```js
$('#btnsubmit').click(function() {
    var seat = [], item;
    $.each($('#place li.' + settings.selectingSeatCss + ' a'), function (index, value) {
        item = $(this).attr('title');                   
        seat.push(item);     
    });
 var bookseats = seat;
 $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'confirm.php',
   data: {'bookseats': bookseats},
 });
});
```

When the user clicks on the `#btnsubmit` button, I want to send this variable(actually an array) to a PHP file named confirm.php.

```html
<form method="POST" action="confirm.php"> 
<div align="center"><input type="Submit" id="btnsubmit" value="Submit" /></div>
</form>
```

In my PHP file, I've written the code to get the sent variable as follows.

```
$bookseats = "";

if(isset($_POST['bookseats']))
{
    $bookseats = $_POST["bookseats"];
    print_r($bookseats);
}
```

When executed, nothing happens in the PHP file(doesn't print the `bookseats`).Is there something wrong with this code?

Comment: use debugger or console.log that you are sending something to php

Comment: There is no code to display the result of your ajax request...

Comment: I can see a couple of things. The form *will* submit, just as it will normally do since you aren't handling the form submission. You'll go to the page, and the ajax will process at the same time... and nothing will be listening to the result.

Get the button out of the form, keep the id, and in a `.then()` method attached to the `ajax` call, build a function that targets a display element with `$('#displayElem').html(response)`

Comment: What's insight in your POST Variable? Can you var_dump it out? You have to implement the "success" callback and console.log() the data which is coming back.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using a "success" callback to get the output of the PHP code. See [`success` callback](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'confirm.php',
  data: {'bookseats': bookseats},
  success: function(data) {
     console.log(data); // or alert(data);
  }
});
```

Also, I think you should stop the propagation of the default behavior of the button, to prevent the browser to redirect the page to the form's action URL:

```
$('#btnsubmit').click(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
```

As @Malovich pointed out, as of jQuery 1.8, you could also use [`.then()`](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/):

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'confirm.php',
  data: {'bookseats': bookseats}
}).then(function(data) {
  console.log(data); // or alert(data);
}, function(){ 
  console.log("Error");
});
```

Comment: `success` is outdated and may be deprecated already; `$ajax().then(function(response){/* response code here */})` is current.

Comment: @Malovich It's not deprecated AFAIK

Comment: @Barmar Right. Nothing in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) mentions it.

Comment: But I also have some data saved in sessions,and after the above code is done,I need to go to the confirm.php page to display the results in it.

Comment: @AjithaMalkanthi In this case, in the success callback you could use `window.location='confirm.php';`, but what is the purpose of your AJAX call if you don't need to stay in the current page?

Comment: Then is there another way to do it?I really didn't know it!please tell?

Comment: The thing is that,when the user clicks the submit button,I want to pass the variable to the php page and display it there with the sessions I told before(The sessions are working fine.The problem is with this variable)...

Comment: success or then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170318/discussion-between-ajitha-malkanthi-and-syscall).