# using ajax to post js variables to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hey guys I have geolocation.html file and test.php file. I am using Ajax to pass var longitude and latitude from geolocation.html to my test.php for processing but it is showing me blank pages. I don't know why? Please help
geolocation.html

```
    <html>
<head>
<script type= "text/javascript" src= "js/jquery.js" > </script>
<script>

//javascript is on the client
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        document.write("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
}


function showPosition(position) {
     var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
     var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

     //Pass longitude and latitude to php how?
     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'test.php',
        data: {lat: latitude,
        lng:longitude}
        });
}

</head>
```

Then my test.php

```
    <?php 
 // $addlat = $_GET['addlat'];
 // $addlong = $_GET['addlong'];
 if (isset($_POST['lat']) && isset($_POST['lng']) )  {
    $lat = $_POST['lat'];
    $lng = $_POST['lng'];
    echo $lat." ".$lng  ; 
}
    ?>
```

Comment: where you call ajax function? and try passing some static latlong first.

Comment: The variables and the ajax call are in the function show position

Comment: but where you call showPosition() ?/

Comment: so the function call will be showPosition(position); in my html file and thats it?

Comment: I tried it didn't work

Comment: You have no `success:` function in `$.ajax`, so it never does anything with the response.

Comment: I'm agree with @Barmar. Or use `.then()`: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50162876).

Answer (score 0):

I modified your geolocation.html file. Hope this will help!

```
<html>
<head>
//ajax lib file
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

//javascript is on the client
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        document.write("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
}


function showPosition(position) {
     var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
     var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

     //Pass longitude and latitude to php how?
      $.post("test.php",
        {
          lat: latitude,
          lng: longitude
        },
        function(data){
            alert(data);

        });

}
</script>
</head>   
<button onclick="getLocation();">GET LOCATION</button>
```